# Improve the performance of non-duplicate concurrent ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrenthashmap

I came across the performance issue when implementing a data structure of **non-duplicate** concurrent ArrayList(or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`).

```
public class NonDuplicateList implements Outputable {
    private Map<Term, Integer> map;
    private List<Term> terms;

    public NonDuplicateList() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        this.terms = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public synchronized int addTerm(Term term) { //bad performance :(
        Integer index = map.get(term);
        if (index == null) {
            index = terms.size();
            terms.add(term);
            map.put(term, index);
        }
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public void output(DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(terms.size());
        for (Term term : terms) {
            term.output(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `Term` and `NonDuplicateList` both implement `Outputable` interface to output.

In order to keep `NonDuplicateList` thread-safe, I use `synchronized` to guard the method `addTerm(Term)` and the performance is as bad as expected, when currently invoking `addTerm`.

It seems that `ConcurrentHashMap` isn't suitable for this case, since it doesn't keep strong data consistency. Any idea how to improve the performance of `addTerm` without losing its thread-safety?

EDIT:

`output` method, i.e. iteration through `NonDuplicateList`, might not be thread-safe since only one thread will access this method after concurrently invoking `addTerm`, but `addTerm` must return the index value immediately as soon as a term is added into the `NonDuplicateList`.

Comment: `It seems that ConcurrentHashMap isn't suitable for this case, since it doesn't keep strong data consistency` - please explain.

Comment: I agree, use ConcurrentHashMap for what you've been doing, don't create your own list

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I've heard that after putting a key-value pair into the ConcurrentHashMap, other thread cannot see this change directly? In my case, duplicate element is not allowed, thus, this kind of inconsistency seems not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to reuse `ConcurrentHashMap` in your implementation if you can sacrifice `addTerm` return type. Instead of returning actual index you can return `boolean` which indicates whether addition was successful or produced duplicate. This will also allow you to remove method synchronization and improve performance:

```
private ConcurrentMap<Term, Boolean> map;
private List<Term> terms;

public boolean addTerm(Term term) {
    Boolean previousValue = map.putIfAbsent(term, Boolean.TRUE);
    if (previousValue == null) {
        terms.add(term);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The return value of a term index cannot be sacrificed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It does not seem like you can use actual index outside of `NonDuplicateList`, why do you need it?

Comment: In order to save space, the index is referred by others which also needs to be output instead of using the term data.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you will not get much faster solution here. The point is to avoid synchronization when you don't need it. If you don't mind weak consistency, using `ConcurrentHashMap` iterator can be significantly cheaper than either preventing other threads from adding items while you're iterating or taking a consistent snapshot when the iterator is created.

On the other hand, when you need synchronization and a consistent iterator, you'll need an alternative for `ConcurrentHashMap`. One that comes to my mind is `java.util.Collections#synchronizedMap`, but it's using synchronization at Object level, so every read/write operation needs to acquire lock, which is a performance overhead.

Take a look at `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, which guarantees average `O(log(n))` performance on a wide variety of operations. It also has a number of operations that ConcurrentHashMap doesn't: `ceilingEntry/Key`, `floorEntry/Key`, etc. It also maintains a sort order, which would otherwise have to be calculated (at notable expense) if you were using a ConcurrentHashMap. Maybe it would be possible to get rid of list+map and use `ConcurrentSkipListMap` instead. Index of element might be computed using `ConcurrentSkipListMap` api.